# SQL add Two date variables (Date + Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Check the below Script

```
SELECT getdate() CurrentDate,getdate()+getdate() NewDate
```

Result is :

```
CurrentDate             NewDate
2016-04-04 13:57:51.713 2132-07-08 03:55:43.427
```

My question is , why year is 2132 and Month is 07 in New Date field.

Comment: why are you adding 2 dates ? what is the expected result ?

Comment: I have no idea what the sum of two dates should be. What do you expect the result of "April 4th + May 11th" to be? "Maypril 11th"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, No, Maypril the 15th :-)

Comment: Suppose i have two **Elapsed time** in diff criteria in a date time format(aa Year:bb Month: cc Day  hh:Hour, mm:Min, SS:Sec) , and now i need to add(sum) these set of elapsed times.

Comment: @AbdulRasheed Are you looking for [this: DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)?

Comment: @Shnugo, check my above comments , i have list of elapsed time in datetime form( xx Year,xx Month, xx days ...) and i need to add some of this. ( so far, i got a good answer from @Squirrel)

Comment: @AbdulRasheed, it depends on the minimal unit you want to get. You might take the seconds of each (DATEDIFF against 1900-01-01 ?), add these seconds and use DATEADD to add the sum of seconds to 1900-01-01?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`1900-01-01` is date 0

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 0)
```

when you add 2 dates together, it is implicitly convert to integer, perform the addition and then convert back to datetime

```
SELECT  CONVERT(INT, getdate()), -- no of days since 1900-01-01
        CONVERT(INT, getdate()) + CONVERT(INT, getdate()), 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(INT, getdate()) + CONVERT(INT, getdate()))
```

It is not logical to add 2 dates. But rather you would add x days to a date using `dateadd( day , x, a_date )`

Comment: Thanx @Squirrel, this is a new lesson for me.

Answer (score 0):

As your dates are going down to seconds you should - as one learns this in school :-) - go down to the smallest unit, do the maths there and then - if needed - go back to any format you want to use for display.

The following will calculate the difference between two DATETIME values.

If your elapsed times are really DATETIME, you must be aware that you get into trouble, when this exceeds 24 hours or when the sum of them does. You should rather change the column type to INT and store the count of elapsed seconds. This is much closer to the *real* meaning and much easier to handle.

But - to give you a hint - this is one approach to calculate with datetime values:

```
CREATE TABLE #test(Elapsed1 DATETIME, Elapsed2 DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES
 ( {d'2000-01-01'},DATEADD(DAY,3,{d'2000-01-01'})) --3 full days
,(GETDATE(),DATEADD(SECOND,180,GETDATE())) --3 minutes

--this would be your table of datetime values
SELECT Elapsed1
      ,Elapsed2
      ,DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d'2000-01-01'},Elapsed2) AS Elapsed1Seconds 
      ,DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d'2000-01-01'},Elapsed2) AS Elapsed2Seconds
      ,DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d'2000-01-01'},Elapsed2)
      -DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d'2000-01-01'},Elapsed1) AS DifferenceSeconds
      ,DATEADD(SECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d'2000-01-01'},Elapsed2)
                     -DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d'2000-01-01'},Elapsed1),{d'2000-01-01'}) AS AddedTimespans
FROM #test;

DROP TABLE #test;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add some time interval to the date variable, you should use DATEADD function.

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDate, DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()) AS NewDate
```

Please note that you can also use negative values to subtract some time interval from a given date. More information on this function usage may be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms186819(v=sql.110).aspx